# How do I declare and initialize this map<pair<int, int>, bool>?

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, stl

While I'm trying to create a map data structure with **Key** as `pair<pair<int, int>, bool` and **Value** as `int`.

- When compiled on xcode, build failed with linker errors
- When compiled on websites like cpp.sh or godbolt.org, it
  throws a template args error

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

typedef std::pair<int,int> pair;

struct comp
{
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(const T &l, const T &r) const
    {
        if (l.first == r.first)
            return l.second > r.second;

        return l.first < r.first;
    }
};

int main()
{
    
    map<pair,bool,comp> mp = 
    {
        {std::make_pair<4,0>,true},
        {std::make_pair<4,1>,true}
    }; //Initializing

    mp.insert(make_pair(3,0),true); //Inserting

    return 0; 
}
```

The reason I wrote a `comp` struct with a template is for key `ordering`.
 But, i technically do not need ordering for the problem I'm solving. 
So when I tried with`unordered_map`, it resulted in similar build errors

Comment: You should include the error message(s) verbatim in your question.  Having said that using `pair` as an alias for `std::pair<int,int>` in conjunction with `using namespace std;` doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Replace angle brackets with paretheses in `make_pair` invocations. `std::pair` is comparable so your `comp` is excess.

Comment: @bipll: u're right, i removed ```comp``` and it worked, Thank you. May be comp is needed if my key was <int,bool>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several syntactic errors in your example, and an ambiguity due to `using namespace std;` whilst defining an alias in the global namespace with a colliding name (`pair`).

Here is your code example after:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<int, int> Pair;

struct comp {
  template <typename T> bool operator()(const T &l, const T &r) const {
    if (l.first == r.first)
      return l.second > r.second;

    return l.first < r.first;
  }
};

int main() {

  std::map<Pair, bool, comp> mp = {
      {std::make_pair(4, 0), true},
      {std::make_pair(4, 1), true}}; // Initializing

  mp.insert({std::make_pair(3, 0), true}); // Inserting

}
```

Comment: thank you, i cannot believe how xcode did not throw a more descriptive error for using angular brackets for ```make_pair```, and missing curly for ```insert```

Comment: @PersistentCache we cannot read the error message at all because you didnt tell use what it is ;). Maybe it is hard to decipher but usually error messages do contain a lot of information, often even suggest fixes